# How to match all words that does not contain two digits in a row?

Tags: python, regex

I have list of values, every one contains "pt" + 2 digits part. But if after that there is "_digitdigit" - this value should be exculded.

should match: `data_pt01_pr, data_pt02_1_pr, data_pt02_2`

should not match:  `data_pt01_01_pr, data_pt22_22, data_pt01_00_ABCD_1_bk_vi`

I was thinking something like [^\d{2}] will do the trick, but it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: That probably doesn't work because you aren't accounting for the underline character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion `(?!...)`:

```
pattern = r'pt\d\d(?!_\d\d)'
```

This pattern matches `pt` followed by two digits *only if* they are not followed by an underscore and two digits.

```
>>> p = re.compile(pattern)
>>> bool(p.search("data_pt01_pr"))
True
>>> bool(p.search("data_pt02_2"))
True
>>> bool(p.search("data_pt01_01_pr"))
False
>>> bool(p.search("data_pt22_22"))
False
```

Comment: Thank you! So this is the only way for all tasks like find something containing 'not smth' and 'not smth'?

Comment: Yes.  But note that it's generally hard to write regular expressions for "negative patterns".  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611853/regular-expression-problem-in-java/1611938#1611938